# Ubuntu - Show active connections?

Tags: bitcoind, ubuntu

How can I see how many active connections there are on `Linux`?

Answer (score 5):

`bitcoin-cli getinfo` will show the number of connections.

`bitcoin-cli getpeerinfo` will give information about individual connections.

Answer (score 2):

(GUI Method) Open Bitcoin Core and open the debug window. On the "console" tab, type in `getconnectioncount`.

You can also hover your mouse over the "connections" icon in the bottom right. (Also in the GUI)

Answer (score 1):

To view active-connections to the Bitcoin Network, simply run `bitcoin-cli getconnectioncount` to return the count within the terminal-output.