# Check number of active peers a node has

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-cli, bitcore

I saw [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/38689/ubuntu-show-active-connections) that you can run `bitcoin-cli getinfo` to see the total number of connections that a node you're running is connected to.  Is there a way to get this information remotely?  For example, say I know that IP X.X.X.X is a bitcoin node, is there a way for me to ask it what nodes it is currently connected to?  Similar to how I can getaddr it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, by design.

Being able to infer connection information of remote nodes would be a leak of network graph information, which is considered private.